# Pi. An estimate or answer.

Tags: geometry

When you estimate pi to be 3.14 and then use it to help you find an answer to a problem, is the answer still considered an estimate because of the 3.14 or is the answer a final answer, not an estimate?

Comment: The number that you get (using 3.14 in place of $\pi$) is an estimate of whatever that number should be... the accuracy of the estimate depends on the specific application.

Comment: So when doing Circumfrence of a circle the answer should not have an equal sign but an estimate sign?

Comment: Correct.  If you want to know the circumference of a circle with radius 1 knowing that $C=2\pi r$ then  $C\approx 2(3.14)(1)=6.28$ but it is not the case that $C=6.28$.

Comment: Why do they not show this in text books? Why do they always show an equal sign?

Comment: I do not know the answer to that.  But I do remember distinctly the day at lunch in middle school when I proved that $\pi$ was a repeating decimal--this was using the "fact" that I was taught that $\pi=\frac{22}{7}$ and not that $\pi\approx \frac{22}{7}$.

Comment: The confusion is frustrating. I wish it was consistently one way or the other. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Many schoolteachers have a fear of math, and we can only try extra hard to make sure the textbooks are correct, and emphasize ways to avoid such errors as this.  (With current salaries, it is unrealistic to get schoolteachers who excel in all subjects.)

Answer (score 0):

Certain texts may be using the equal sign because of significant digits. For instance, if you've measured the radius of a circle and found it to be 1, as in the comment above, then to find the circumference you'd find is $2*3.14*1 = 6.28$. Because the accuracy of the measurement is using less significant digits (one SD) than your estimate of pi (3 SDs), then your calculation is considered "equal" to the correct answer.

Let's say you took the measurement of another circle and found its radius to be 4.578 cm. Now your calculation would be $2*3.14*4.578\approx 28.7$ cm, because now you've got at most 3 SDs because you approximated $\pi$ to 3.14. Not 100% sure if this accurate but it makes sense to me. If I'm wrong someone let me know and I'll delete my answer.